# TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, datatables

I am trying to work with jQuery's Datatable JS for my project from [this](https://www.datatables.net/) link.

I downloaded the complete library from the same source. All the examples given in the package seem to work fine, but when I try to incorporate them in my `WebForms`,the CSS,JS do not **work at all.**

Here is what I have done  :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <table id="myTable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Start date</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Start date</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody>
               <!-- table body -->
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script src="js/jquery.dataTables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#myTable').DataTable();
        });
    </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

My file structure for the JS and CSS in my Solution looks as follows :

[image: File structure of JS and CSS in solution]

I have added all the necessary JS and CSS references as shown in the manual. Still the rendering isn't as expected. There is no CSS and even the JS doesn't work.

Also in the console i get the following errors:

```
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
```

I have still not bound any dynamic data here (like within a repeater or so) still it is not working.

Can someone please guide me in the right direction for this problem ?

Comment: Whatever the code I have written was perfectly fine, but I also got this same error. After long analysis, I just restarted my PC as I didn't restart since last 7 days. Then, my code started working.

Comment: @Ashokkumar: you got lucky probably!

Answer (score 199, accepted):

#### CAUSE

There could be multiple reasons for this error.

- jQuery DataTables library is missing.
- jQuery library is loaded **after** jQuery DataTables.
- Multiple versions of jQuery library is loaded.

#### SOLUTION

Include **only one** version of jQuery library version 1.7 or newer **before** jQuery DataTables.

For example:

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

See [jQuery DataTables: Common JavaScript console errors](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-common-javascript-console-errors/#typeerror-datatable-is-not-a-function) for more information on this and other common console errors.

Comment: My issue was the second one: "jQuery library is loaded after jQuery DataTables." Moved the loading script at the end and it worked.

Comment: Why does DataTables not make in huge bold letters at top of every single demo...  "YOU MUST LOAD JQUERY JS BEFORE DATATABLES JS".  One line of text would save humans a lot of wasted time :)

Comment: You can find the cdn here too: https://cdn.datatables.net/

Comment: I cannot stress how important order is in your Layout file. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: In my case, multiple jquery were loaded!

Answer (score 78):

This worked for me. But make sure to load the jquery.js before the preferred dataTable.js file. Cheers!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/data-table/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

 <script>$(document).ready(function () {
    $.noConflict();
    var table = $('# your selector').DataTable();
});</script>
```

Comment: The $.noConflict() call in the method was the key for me. Thanks.

Comment: @jrebs thank you for that tip! I was pulling my hair out and the noConflict was the one that made it to work!!

Answer (score 46):

I got this error because I found out that I referenced jQuery twice.

The first time: on the master page (`_Layout.cshtml`) in ASP.NET MVC, and then again on one current page so I commented out the one on the master page.

If you are using ASP.NET MVC this snippet could help you

```
@*@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")*@//comment this line 
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

and in the current page I added these lines

```
<script src="~/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<!-- #region datatables files -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<!-- #endregion -->
```

Hope this help you even if don't use ASP.NET MVC

Comment: Actually, I commented jquery.min.js within _Layout.cshtml. However, what really worked for me is putting @RenderSection("scripts", required: false) at the very bottom after all <scripts></scripts> elements.

Comment: thanks a lot, your answer ended 4 hours of installing and reinstalling jquery datatables! I have a question though: what If I needed jQuery in _Layout.cshtml and needed datatables in myView.cshtml, what shall I do since not mentioning jQuery in myView.cshtml will cause "jQuery is not defined" ?

Answer (score 23):

if some reason two versions of jQuery are loaded (which is not recommended), calling `$.noConflict(true)` from the second version will return the globally scoped jQuery variables to those of the first version.

Sometimes it could be issue with older version (or not stable) of JQuery files

Solution use `$.noConflict();`

```
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.dataTables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$.noConflict();
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    $('#myTable').DataTable();
});
// Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

Answer (score 16):

Here is the complete set of JS and CSS required for the export table plugin to work perfectly.

Hope it will save your time

```
   <!--Import jQuery before export.js-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>


    <!--Data Table-->
    <script type="text/javascript"  src=" https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src=" https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>

    <!--Export table buttons-->
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.24/build/pdfmake.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.24/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.1/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>

<!--Export table button CSS-->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
```

javascript to add export buttons on the table with id = `tbl`

```
  $('#tbl').DataTable({
                        dom: 'Bfrtip',
                        buttons: [
                            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
                        ]
                    });
```

Result :-

[image]

Comment: I was able to do this without the "export table buttons" script calls. Good stuff.

Answer (score 15):

Same error occurs when working with DataTables in a Laravel project. Even if the following solutions are tried, the error still remains:

1. making sure jQuery is included
2. include jQuery before including the DataTables
3. making sure only one version of jQuery is added

In order to remove the error, after making sure the above conditions are fulfilled, add "defer" to the tag which includes the DataTables. For example,

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" defer></script>
```

Answer (score 10):

### There can be two reasons for that error:

### **First**

You are loding `jQuery.DataTables.js` before `jquery.js` so for that :-

*You need to load `jQuery.js` before you load `jQuery.DataTables.js`*

### **Second**

You are using two versions of `jQuery.js` on the same page so for that :-

*Try to use the higher version and make sure both links have same version of `jQuery`*

Comment: A potential issue to achieve "TypeError: $(…).DataTable is not a function" since Datatables started providing a pick-your-own download builder is that you select jquery in the download but also already have it on your page.

Comment: Just to be clear - this error is thrown from OTHER sources as well. I had them in the right order and was not using two jQuerys. Just in case some other poor soul comes along....  When it works DataTables is wonderful but it is way to flaky for my liking (about an hour in to getting another ****** installation to work!

Answer (score 5):

I tried many things but my solution was adding "defer" after html script that you included datatables.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.js" defer></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Honestly, this took hours to get this fixed. Finally only one thing worked a reconfirmation to solution provided by "Basheer AL-MOMANI". Which is just putting statement

```
   @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

within `_Layout.cshtml` file after all `<script></script>` elements and also commenting the jquery script in the same file. Secondly, I had to add

```
 $.noConflict();
```

within jquery function call at another *.cshtml file as:

```
 $(document).readyfunction () {
          $.noConflict();
          $("#example1").DataTable();
         $('#example2').DataTable({
              "paging": true,
              "lengthChange": false,
              "searching": false,
              "ordering": true,
              "info": true,
              "autoWidth": false,
          });

        });
```

Answer (score 3):

I know its late
Buy can help someone

This could also happen if you don't add `$('#myTable').DataTable();` inside the `document.ready`

So instead of this

`$('#myTable').DataTable();`

Try This

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myTable').DataTable();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I have Added **defer** to the data table jquery library reference. Now it is working for me.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js" defer></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this error also.  For whatever reason I had originally coded

```
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable({
    "paging": false,
    "order": [[ 4, "asc" ]]
});
```

This would not throw the error sometimes and other times it would.  By changing code to

```
$('#myTable').DataTable({
    "paging": false,
    "order": [[ 4, "asc" ]]
});
```

Error appears to have stopped

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution was to delete cookies from the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue in Flask, I had already a template that loaded JQuery, Popper and Bootstrap. I was extending that template into other template that I was using as a base to load the page that had the table.

For some reason in Flask apparently the files in the outer template load before the files in the tables above in the hierarchy (the ones you are extending) so JQuery was loading before the DataTables files causing the issue.

I had to create another template where I run all my imports of JS CDNs in the same place, that solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens that the script (initializing of datatable) is embedded in a general page template, so if one of the pages that actually does not have any table and you did not import the jquery related files for datatable, you face this error, since the general initialization still is looking for that. (**This was in my case**)

Solution: Is to wrap the initialization of datatable inside a codition that check presence of the library before that:

Here is practical example of it.

```
if (typeof jQuery.fn.DataTable != "undefined"){
    $('#accordionExample table').DataTable( {
        "pageLength": 5,
        "info": false,
        "order": [[ 1, "desc" ]]
    } );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may also happen if you write Datatable instead of DataTable. (DataTable T must be capital). this is a beginner's mistake.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#category-table').DataTable({
                // Your Code
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure that you aligned your scripts as described above, please make sure you DataTable word case is correct.

Before

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myTable').Datatable();
});
```

After

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myTable').DataTable();
});
```

small t is creating problem, when I changed this t to T it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Nuget packages.  I had to remove jQuery nuget packages to get this to work.