# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

I have that error on my php file.
I have check my libraries order but i think is correct.
This is my script code:

```
< script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js">
</script>

<script>    

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#tablaLocalizaciones').dataTable({

            "ajax": "tabla.php",
                "columns":[
                { "data":"nombre"},
                { "data":"tipo"},


                ]



        });

    } );

</script>
```

any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Look at your URLs.  The first is loading according to the page's default scheme, which is probably HTTP.  The second is using HTTPS.  If this is the case, the browser will reject the second script because you can't mix secure and insecure content.

Comment: If the site is indeed loaded over http I don't see the problem @codenoire?

Comment: @OP just remove the space in your html script element...

Comment: If the site is loaded over HTTP, then modern browsers won't load the scripts over HTTPS.  Conversely, if the site is loaded over HTTPS, they won't load scripts over HTTP.  Read more here.  https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/what-is-mixed-content?hl=en

Comment: That doesn't make any sense @codenoire. Only the last part is true.

Comment: I changed it - had a typo.

Comment: @codenoire, if you are on http:// you can load https:// resources, you can not do the inverse

Comment: Of course browsers will load ssl resources from non ssl pages.

Comment: The problemas was that i had multiples references to Jquery :) problem fixed!

Answer (score 1):

You need to load jQuery before you load any jQuery-related code such as jQuery DataTables, see below:

```
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.dataTables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also, for production version it's recommended to load minified version (ending with .min.js instead). You can see it  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31227844/typeerror-datatable-is-not-a-function)

Comment: The OP is loading jQuery first.

Comment: I had multiples references to jquery! that was the error :)