# Cannot get DataTable to initialize in MVC App

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I am populating a table through a model which is using being filled with the Entity Framework. I can fill the table fine but it takes far too long to load and makes the page very unresponsive while loading and utlises too much memory.

So I am trying to use DataTables in order to limit data shown while still allowing me to search all the data in the table. However I cannot get it to initialise. I have followed many guides, linked JQuery, Linked the datatables API, the CSS but still does not work. It just shows a normal table.

Here is my Controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Index(System.Web.Mvc.FormCollection collection)
    {
        DateTime lastMonth = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-3);
        string selectedList = collection["list"];
        string selectedGroupType = collection["grouptype"];


        List<SelectListItem> ddl = new List<SelectListItem>();
        List<SelectListItem> ddl2 = new List<SelectListItem>();
        var entities = new TableEntities();


        var stock = entities.stocks.Take(0).ToList();

        //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(selectedList);
        //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(selectedGroupType);
        if (selectedList == null && selectedGroupType == null)
        {
            stock = entities.stocks.Take(0).ToList();
        }
        else if (selectedGroupType == "grouptype=Select+GroupType" || selectedGroupType == null || selectedGroupType == "")
        {
            if (selectedList == null || selectedList == "")
            {
                stock = entities.stocks.Where(g => (g.DateEntered >= lastMonth)).Distinct().ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                stock = entities.stocks.Where(g => (g.ProductGroup == selectedList) && (g.DateEntered >= lastMonth)).Distinct().ToList();
            }
        }
        else if (selectedList == "list=Select+Company" || selectedList == null || selectedList == "")
        {
            stock = entities.stocks.Where(g => (g.GroupType == selectedGroupType) && (g.DateEntered >= lastMonth)).Distinct().ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            stock = entities.stocks.Where(g => (g.ProductGroup == selectedList) && (g.GroupType == selectedGroupType) && (g.DateEntered >= lastMonth)).Distinct().ToList();
        }

        var stocktemp = entities.stocks.Select(g => g.ProductGroup).Distinct().ToList();
        foreach (var item in stocktemp)
            ddl.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = item });
        ViewData["list"] = ddl;


        stocktemp = entities.stocks.Select(g => g.GroupType).Distinct().ToList();
        foreach (var item in stocktemp)
            ddl2.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = item });
        ViewData["grouptype"] = ddl2;

        return View(stock);


        //Select(u => { u.StockId, u.ProductGroup , u.Category , u.GroupType , u.ItemType , u.Model , u.SerialNo , u.Status , u.DateArrived , u.CurrentLocation , u.Description , u.TerminalId }).
    }
```

And here is my View:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.stock>
<script src="~/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700,300,100&amp;lang=en">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<body>
    <form class="my-form" method="post" action="~/Table/Index">
        <div class="filter">
            @Html.DropDownList("list", "Select Company")
            @Html.DropDownList("grouptype", "Select GroupType")
            <br type />
            <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for Model">
            <input type="text" id="myInput2" onkeyup="myFunction2()" placeholder="Search for SerialNo">
            <br />
            <button input type="submit"> Submit </button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="scrollingTable">
        <table class="table-fill" id="myTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StockId)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProductGroup)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Category)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.GroupType)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ItemType)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Model)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SerialNo)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NR)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Status)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DateArrived)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CurrentLocation)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TerminalId)
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StockId)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductGroup)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Category)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.GroupType)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ItemType)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Model)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SerialNo)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NR)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateArrived)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CurrentLocation)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TerminalId)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>

        </table>
    </div>

    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            // Declare variables
            var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
            input = document.getElementById("myInput");
            filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
            table = document.getElementById("myTable");
            tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

            // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
            for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
                td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[5];
                if (td) {
                    if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                        tr[i].style.display = "";
                    } else {
                        tr[i].style.display = "none";
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        function myFunction2() {
            // Declare variables
            var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
            input = document.getElementById("myInput2");
            filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
            table = document.getElementById("myTable");
            tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

            // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
            for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
                td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[6];
                if (td) {
                    if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                        tr[i].style.display = "";
                    } else {
                        tr[i].style.display = "none";
                    }
                }
            }
        }



    </script>


    <script>
    $(function () {
        $("#myTable").dataTable();
    })
    </script>
</body>
```

I cannot understand why it doesnt work, I have tried changing the Tables class to Display, I have tried changing the link to various ones posted on other Stack questions and blog posts but still no lock.

Specifically I need the search functionality and limiting how many columns displayed.

Thanks.

EDIT: I am receiving this error on Chrome developer tools:

Index:47368 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function(…)(anonymous function) @ Index:47368fire @ jquery-1.10.2.js:3062fireWith @ jquery-1.10.2.js:3174ready @ jquery-1.10.2.js:447completed @ jquery-1.10.2.js:118

Which I have tried to fix in this edit however I am still receiving it.

Comment: The `</form>` is in an odd spot. Try closing the form right before `<div class="scrollingTable">`

Comment: Done, Changed edit too. However this did not fix the issue.

Comment: Try putting the datatable initialization javascript at the very end of the file or put it inside `$(document).ready(function()`. If that doesn't work, you'll need to debug client side (Chrome developer tools or equivalent).

Comment: I am recieving error Index:47368 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function(…)(anonymous function) @ Index:47368fire @ jquery-1.10.2.js:3062fireWith @ jquery-1.10.2.js:3174ready @ jquery-1.10.2.js:447completed @ jquery-1.10.2.js:118

Which is strange to me as I am linking the datatables? I will update my edit too.

Comment: Okay I fixed the issue, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I have fixed this by using this previous answer:

[TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31227844/typeerror-datatable-is-not-a-function)

The issue was I am referencing Jquery twice, so I commented the shared reference and it works!