# Want to get Page number using Datatable jQuery function but it generate Typeerror

Tags: jquery, datatables

```
// Page number of datatable
    var table = $('#example1').DataTable();
    var info = table.page.info();   
    pageNo = info.page+1;

    $.ajax({
        url:"<?=ADMIN_PRODUCT_EDIT?>",
        type:"post",
        async:"true",
        data:{pid:id,pageNo:pageNo},
        beforeSend:function(data){
            //alert(data);  
        },
        success:function(data){
            alert(data);
            $("#product_edit_form").html(data);
        },
        error:function(data){
            alert(data);
        },
    });
```

> TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function[Learn More]
>   admin_product:2774:14 editProduct
>   http://localhost/healthvit-new/admin_product:2774:14 onclick

Comment: what is in line 14?

Comment: $(...).DataTable is not a function . Did you define datatable.js?

Comment: Yes, i have define js above the function.

Comment: share screenshot like https://snag.gy/dqN7mM.jpg. 
You can use https://snag.gy/ for sharing.

Comment: Code : https://snag.gy/MgyuEw.jpg
Error : https://snag.gy/qVwBHj.jpg

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/31227844/6381711

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check this:**

The error was occured when the datatable function is called before the script is loaded correctly or completely.

The below function will call the script, when the function is not found.

```
   function editProduct(id) {
      if (!$.fn.DataTable) {
         $.getScript('https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js',
                 function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
                    if (jqxhr == 200) {
                       if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('.no-ordering')) {
                          var table = $('#dtTable').DataTable();
                       } else {
                          var table = $('#dtTable').DataTable({
                             paging: false,
                             searching: false
                          });
                       }
                       /* var table = $('.no-ordering').DataTable(); */
                       var info = table.page.info();
                       pageNo = info.page + 1;


                       $.ajax({
                          url: "<?= $ADMIN_PRODUCT_EDIT ?>",
                          type: "post",
                          async: "true",
                          data: {pid: id, pageNo: pageNo},
                          beforeSend: function (data) {
                          },
                          success: function (data) {
                             $("#product_edit_form").html(data);
                          },
                          error: function (data) {
                          }
                       });
                    }
                 }
         );
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest of your code, I can only guess that you forgot to include the DataTable library, or only have the CSS. You can find instructions [on DataTable's website](https://datatables.net/manual/installation) .

Comment: the code i am trying that got from DataTable website. this code create problem when i'm using $.post() or $.ajax() methods.