# TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function: DataTables not working without $.noConflict(true)

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I just discovered [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) and I'm playing with it. The page's task is to search posts based on client's parameters, returning a JSON that fills the table anytime without reloading the page. The problem I'm facing are:

- `TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function`. jQuery is (perfectly) loaded **before** DataTables plugin is (perfectly) loaded. jQuery is not loaded twice (unless DataTables loads jQuery on its own, but I don't think so). 
  [image]
  The loading order is correct. I'm using Laravel and jQuery is loaded as first script in every page, in `layouts/app.blade.php`. All the views extend that layout and the specific scripts of each view are loaded *after* it in the `@section('scripts')`.
- I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43114901/6465600) and I called `$.noConflict(true)` before calling `$('#results').DataTable()`. Now the plugin works fine, but everything else related to jQuery returns `$ is not a function` (especially new $.ajax calls).

I want to understand why `TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function` is thrown and solve it without using `$.noConflict(true)`.

Does anyone have any idea?

Scripts' loading order:

`layouts/app.blade.php`

```
<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/admin/main.js') }}"></script>

@yield('scripts')
```

`index.blade.php`

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('scripts')
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ secure_asset('js/helpers.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ secure_asset('js/admin/Values.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ secure_asset('js/SVGTools.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ secure_asset('js/admin/Search.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ secure_asset('js/admin/Delete.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ secure_asset('js/admin/blog/post/PostSearch.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ secure_asset('js/admin/blog/post/index.behaviour.js') }}"></script>
@endsection
```

Here's the part of the code which displays the data into the table (in `PostSearch.js`):

```
this.search = function () {
    var getData = function () {
        var v = new Values();
        v.collect('getValue');
        console.log(v.getCollection.raw);

        return v.getCollection.raw;
    };

    /**
     * Display the data into the table.
     *
     * @param {Object} data
     * @param {Function} callback
     */
    var displayData = function (data, callback) {
        if ( ! data.length ) {
            //  No result
            document.getElementById('no-result').innerText = 'Nessun risultato per "'+document.getElementById('search').value+'"';
        } else {
            //  Yes results
            document.getElementById('no-result').innerText = "";

            // $.noConflict(true);
            $('#results').DataTable( {
                "ordering": true,
                "data": data,
                "searching": true,
                "columns": [
                    {'data':'id'},
                    {'data':'title'},
                    {'data':'category'},
                    {'data':'article'},
                    {'data':'likes'},
                    {'data':'status'},
                    {'data':'publication_datetime'},
                    {'data':'id'}
                ]
            });
        }

        callback();
    };

    /**
     * Empty the table.
     */
    var emptyData = function () {
        document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].innerHTML = '';
    };

    new Search({
        events: {
            "click": document.getElementById('search')
        },
        url: function () {
            return route_resource_admin_blog('posts', 'show', 'search')
        },
        data: function () {
            return getData();
        },
        clear: function () {
            emptyData();
        },
        previousStuff: function (target, searchTerm) {

        },
        successCallback: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log('SUCCESS');
            displayData(data, function () {

            });
        },
        errorCallback: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        },
        beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) {

        },
        complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {

        }
    });
};
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the comment! I'm using Laravel and jQuery is loaded in *every* page in `layouts/app.blade.php`. All the views extend that layout and the specific scripts of each page are loaded *after* it in `@section('scripts')`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I edited my question adding the code that shows what scripts I'm loading and in what order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I unfortunately didn't find the problem's origin, using `jQuery.noConflict()` instead of `$.noConflict()` makes the script working right, without making the following `$` alias crash.