# Laravel and Datatables AJAX

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatables

I'm sure this question might have been asked a long time ago but I have searched everywhere online and don't quite get the results that I am looking for.

I am busy building a app that makes use of Datatables Jquery plugin and everything seems to be working as I can access the route and the data is passed to the frontend but no data is being display in my table.

Here is my Controller Function:

```
public function index()
{
    return view('pages.admin.artikels.index');
}

public function getArticles()
{
    return DataTables::of(Post::query())->make();
}
```

And my routes file:

```
Route::middleware(['super'])->group(function () {
Route::get('/super/artikels/', 'AdminPostsController@index')->name('super.artikels');
Route::get('/artikels/data', 'AdminPostsController@getArticles')->name('article.data');
```

});

And my Blade File

```
    @extends('layouts.app')

@section('page_title')
Artikel Administrasie
@endsection

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="text-teal-dark mb-3 font-weight-bold">
                    <span class="fa fa-angle-double-right text-orange"></span> Artikel Administrasie
                </h5>
                <div id="formContainer">
                    <table id="articles" class="table bg-white table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Id</th>
                                <th>Title</th>
                                <th>Body</th>
                                <th>Author</th>
                                <th>Published</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
@push('scripts')
<script>
    $('#articles').DataTable({
        serverSide: false,
        processing: false,
        ajax: "{{ route('article.data') }}",
        columns: [
            { data: 'id' },
            { data: 'title' },
            { data: 'body' },
            { data: 'user_id' },
            { data: 'created_at' },
        ]
    });
</script>
@endpush
```

Here is the response from the frontend when looking at the Xhr

```
    {draw: 0, recordsTotal: 2, recordsFiltered: 2, data: [,…], queries: [,…], input: {_: "1538557939697"}}
data: [,…]
0: {id: "1", title: "Toets Artikel", slug: "toets-artikel", image: "", body: "This is a test article",…}
1: {id: "2", title: "Toets Artikel 2", slug: "toets-artikel-twee", image: "",…}
draw: 0
input: {_: "1538557939697"}
queries: [,…]
recordsFiltered: 2
recordsTotal: 2
```

Any help with this matter would be greatly appreciated

Comment: add the script within ` $(document).ready(function () {})` and `make(true);`

Comment: When doing that it returns jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).DataTable is not a function TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function...jQuery is loaded on the page and when I remove it out of the $(doument).ready() it gives no error

Comment: Just for the record, all of this logic could be greatly simplified using https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables (Laravel Datatables API)

Comment: I am using that library

Comment: Have you added package for datatable?

Comment: have you added datatable jquery client library in your scripts?

Comment: Yes using yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "^8.8

Comment: yeah scripts are in my app.blade.php
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.18/r-2.2.2/datatables.min.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.18/r-2.2.2/datatables.min.js"></script>

Comment: try changing `serverSide: false,` to `true` and `processing: false,`  to `true`

Comment: Same result no data

Comment: check your console getting any error?

Comment: processing just hangs on the screen and no data in table . No errors in console

Answer (score 0):

Might be a problem with columns, try the [docs](https://datatables.yajrabox.com/eloquent/basic-columns) suggested format:

```
<script>
    $('#articles').DataTable({
        serverSide: false,
        processing: false,
        ajax: "{{ route('article.data') }}",
        columns: [
            {data: 0, name: 'id'},
            {data: 1, name: 'title'},
            {data: 2, name: 'body'},
            {data: 3, name: 'created_at'},
            {data: 4, name: 'updated_at'}
        ]
    });
</script>
```

Comment: nope tried that only returns error: request unknow parameter

Comment: Look at the docs, in the comment: *return Datatables::of($articles)->make(**true**);*

Comment: passing true does not make a difference result remains the same

Comment: {draw: 1, recordsTotal: 2, recordsFiltered: 2, data: [,…], queries: [,…],…}
data: [,…]
draw: 1
input: {draw: "1", columns: [,…], order: [{column: "0", dir: "asc"}], start: "0", length: "10",…}
queries: [,…]
recordsFiltered: 2
recordsTotal: 2

Comment: It must be a client side error then. This has to be made: add the script within `$(document).ready(function () {})` and `make(true);`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31227844/typeerror-datatable-is-not-a-function

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys I got it fixed by moving the jQuery function out of the blade and into a snippet that manages my ajax sources. Thanks for the help