# Datatable is not working on server, but does in localhost

Tags: datatable

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

**Error message**:

> jquery.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).DataTable is not a
>   function TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
>       at HTMLDocument.

(http://crecheskincare.ml/reservationSelect.php?approved:589:21) at l (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js:2:29375) at c (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js:2:29677) undefined

Comment: Correct the paths ...? I really dont see any question here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31227844/typeerror-datatable-is-not-a-function)