# Error TypeError: $(…).DataTable is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have php file contains DataTable it's working without any errors but If I try to include html page inside the php page it will produce the following error :

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function

As this answer tells us the error in the order of jquery
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31229338/9984938 but because I'm newbie to javascript I don't know if is any error in my order to scripts files

**Scripts in php file**

```js
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

The second file is html
**Scripts in html file**

```js
<script src="assets/web/assets/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/popper/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/tether/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/smoothscroll/smooth-scroll.js"></script>
<script src="assets/dropdown/js/script.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/touchswipe/jquery.touch-swipe.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/viewportchecker/jquery.viewportchecker.js"></script>
<script src="assets/theme/js/script.js"></script>
<script src="assets/formoid/formoid.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Only load jQuery.js once...before all plugins. Loading the second version wipes out the first that datatables assigned itself to

Comment: @charlietfl I deleted it now from html file (<script src="assets/web/assets/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>) it produces the same error

Comment: OK so what is full script order now?

Comment: @charlietfl same order only I have removed the first script from html file

Comment: Where is "$(...)" pointing? Can you check please if it really exist in your DOM?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (semesterReport.php:346)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: It looks like you're loading `bootstrap.min.js` *after* `dataTables.bootstrap.min.js`, which doesn't seem right.

Comment: @freedomn-m yes you are right It worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was gone after I have deleted this two scripts from the html file.

```js
<script src="assets/web/assets/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```