# 'Responsive' datatable container DT::datatable in blogdown using widgetframe

Tags: r, r-markdown, dt, hugo, blogdown

I may be using the term "responsive" incorrectly in this context but I am trying to create a table using DT::datatable in blogdown/Hugo where the container adjusts to the "Show entries" selection, like the first table on the [DT page](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/). I am able to do this in a regular html document using knitr/R markdown but cannot get this behavior in blogdown. My understanding is that to have an html widget in blogdown (with Hugo) I need to use widgetframe package. Cool. The widgetframe documentation has a demonstration with the DT package [here (bottom of page)](https://rawgit.com/bhaskarvk/widgetframe/examples/rmarkdown/knitr_example.html) . As you can see though, when you adjust the "Show entries" the container stays the same.

A minimal example for straight-up R Markdown/knitr html document where the container responds to "Show entries".

```
library(DT)
datatable(iris)
```

A minimal example using widgetframe in blogdown where the container does not respond to "Show entries".

```
library(widgetframe)
library(DT)
dt <-  datatable(
  head(iris, 20), 
  options = list(
     columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets = 5)),
     pageLength = 5, lengthMenu = c(5, 10, 15, 20)),
  fillContainer = T)

frameWidget(dt, height = 350, width = '95%')
```

I have tried manually controlling the height in both the frameWidget and DT commands. I can control the container size but cannot get it to respond to the number of "Show entries". Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the `widgetframe` package. Don't set `fillContainer`, it will force the DT table to fit in the container. The default `DT::datatable(df)` will do exactly what you expected.

Here is a full-text example of a blogdown post:

````
---
title: A showcase for responsive DT table
date: '2019-12-17'
---

```{r}
DT::datatable(head(iris, 20))
```
````

Comment: thank you for the suggestion @tc-zhang. Unfortunately this makes a table with only the header row only and no other data, no other rows.

Comment: [My working example in my blogdown site](http://tc.rbind.io/post/2019/12/17/showcase-for-responsive-dt-table/)

Comment: [Rmd source](https://github.com/rbind/blogsite/blob/master/content/post/2019-12-17-showcase-for-responsive-dt-table.Rmd) Hope this helps.

Comment: I still have the same issue but thanks to your example TC Zhang I am now pretty sure this is a problem with my Hugo theme (which is Academic Hugo) . I still get the same thing, header row only, nothing else.

Comment: can you provide your repo?

Comment: Of course. Here is the [demo page](https://istmobiome.rbind.io/projects/trans-water/test/) with several examples. Here is a [table](https://istmobiome.rbind.io/projects/trans-water/d1/) from the demo page that is responsive in a stand-alone html, and here is the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/istmobiome/web/blob/master/content/projects/trans-water/test.Rmd) for the demo. Thank you for your help TC Zhang.

Comment: Found the problem, jquery loaded multiple times. [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31227844/typeerror-datatable-is-not-a-function). Please file an issue to the Hugo academic theme repo. This is beyond what I can debug.

Comment: I submitted this issue to the Academic GitHub repo [#1493](https://github.com/gcushen/hugo-academic/issues/1493).

Comment: and then it was rejected because apparently this is not a bug.