# Receiving a TypeError when trying to run or initiate dataTables.js

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, datatables

I'm trying to run or initiate script using a plugin called `dataTables.js`. I've managed to import the library using `ES6` import statement along with the `jquery` dependency. When I tried to run or initiate the plugin I get an error as shown below

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: (0 , _jquery.default)(...).DataTable is not a function TypeError: (0 , _jquery.default)(...).DataTable is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.eval (https://juwto.csb.app/src/index.js:13:37)
    at j (https://juwto.csb.app/src/jquery.js:1977:29)
    at k (https://juwto.csb.app/src/jquery.js:1983:19)
```

Sandbox Link - https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-chaplygin-juwto?file=/index.html

[image]

I can't seem to find a proper solution or answer even though I managed to import the libraries properly

```
import $ from "./jquery";
import _dt from "./datatables";

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#table").DataTable({
    paging: false,
    bFilter: false,
    bInfo: false
  });
});
```

Comment: Your table id is `table_id`, not `table`. Change this `$("#table").DataTable({` to this `$("#table_id").DataTable({` and if problems persists, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31227844/typeerror-datatable-is-not-a-function

Comment: You want to import `jquery` and `datatables` in `index.js` only?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the path is correct, try to import DataTables like this: `import "./datatables.net";`

Comment: This will cause a `ModuleNotFoundError
Could not find module in path: './datatables.net' relative to '/src/index.js'`

Comment: How did you installed/imported DataTables into your project?

Comment: You can check it here `https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-chaplygin-juwto?file=/index.html` basically I just uploaded the  `datatables.js` which I got from the repository or website

Comment: Could you please download DataTables sources again from https://datatables.net/download/ . Be sure to download the DataTables package only - without jQuery.

Comment: I just did that and the error is still the same, this just downloading the `DataTables` package only

Comment: Another possible solution is adding DataTables using NPM or Yarn and import/require it in the code like `import "datatables.net";` or `const dataTable = require("datatables.net")();`

Comment: With these lack of details, can you try to download DataTables with jQuery bundled? Remove your jQuery sources. I've read multiple version of jQuery can cause that error.

Answer (score 1):

Well you have a few errors, the first one is what S. Esteves say, your import should be like this

```
import "./datatables";
```

The second one is what dani says, I mean that you used a wrong id.

```
$("#table_id").DataTable({
    paging: false,
    bFilter: false,
    bInfo: false
 });
```

And the last one is that jquery is beign loaded after DataTable. I think that unfortunately the datatable.js cannot be loaded conditionally or on-the-fly, so I suggest you to add the scripts in the head of your index.html file. You also need to load the css and don't forget that jquery needs to be first.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"
    />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"
    ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="button">button</div>

    <table id="table_id" class="display">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Column 1</th>
          <th>Column 2</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>192.168.254.120</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>D</td>
          <td>192.168.254.121</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>C</td>
          <td>192.168.254.122</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>192.168.254.123</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#table_id").DataTable();
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Either way I will try to think of a solution for imports, I will come back here if I get something, I hope I have helped you!