# How can i display MYSQL Data using DataTables using While Loop

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatable

How can i display Data from MYSQL table using DataTables
  I tried  but Top part shown me
 [image]

Bottom Shows Records from MYSQL table.

I want DataTables to read Mysql data display as shown in the picture below

[image]

//bottstrap html code

```
<div class="panel-body">
            <div class="dataTable_wrapper">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
                       <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th>Brand Name</th>
                             <th>Size</th>
                          </tr>
                         </thead>
```

// php

```
       $record = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ts127 ORDER BY Manufacturer");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($record)) {

       if()
         {
         }
       elseif ($row['field1']==$XXX) 
{   
     echo'<table style="table-layout:fixed;" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">';
     // When i remove the above table code works fine for the first record or first row but other listed as a normal text
                echo "<tr'>";                 
                  echo "<td style=' width:150px;  text-align:left; padding: 10px;vertical-align: middle;'>";echo $row['Brand_Name'];echo"</td>";
                  echo "<td style='width:110px;  text-align:left; vertical-align: middle;'>";echo $row['Size'];"</td>";
                       ....

    echo '<tr/></tbody></table>';
 }
```

//JS Code

```
  <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
            responsive: true
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: could you show me the Js code please

Comment: @FahedAlkaabi i added it to the question or you want to see the content of `jquery.dataTables.min.js`

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, You doing a lot of things of PHP and the code is not completed. So I can't judge you PHP code. - Js code and html nothing wrong with it - On you browser check the console on the developing tools (Google Chrome F12) and see if there is any errors

Comment: Your PHP code is not clear, what is this $XXX, or $YYY or the reset values in if condition. Also in while loop you should repeat the tr tag not table tag

Comment: @GoudaElalfy Yes When i remove this line `echo'<table style="table-layout:fixed;" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">';` it works but for the first row only

Comment: You should remove the second table tag, you already open 1 which have a titles, your all could should be <table><thead></thead> <tbody> trs here through while loop </tbody></table>

Comment: @GoudaElalfy When i remove the table works fine but only for the first row

Comment: Did you remove closing tbody and table outside while loop? If yes update your code

Comment: @GoudaElalfy you the man Working Fine It when i remove `</tbody></table>` from the end. Thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mistake was looping the table and tbody, you should be more careful about opening and closing the HTML tags

```
<?php
$record = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ts127 ORDER BY Manufacturer");
echo'<table style="table-layout:fixed;" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">';
    echo '<thead>';
        echo '<tr>';
            echo '<th>Brand Name</th>';
            echo '<th>Size/th>';
        echo '</tr>';
    echo '</thead>';
    echo '<tbody>';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($record)) {
        if (($row['field1']==$XXX || $row['field1']==$YYY ) && ($row['field2']>=$field1sw && $row['field1']<=$largesw) && ($txtbrand != "" && $size1=="" && $row['field2'] != "" && $row['Brand_Name']!="") ) 
        {   
            echo "<tr'>";                 
                echo "<td style=' width:150px;  text-align:left; padding: 10px;vertical-align: middle;'>";echo $row['Brand_Name'];echo"</td>";
                echo "<td style='width:110px;  text-align:left; vertical-align: middle;'>";echo $row['Size'];"</td>";
                   ....
            echo '</tr>';
        }
    }
    echo '</tbody>';
echo '</table>';
?>
```

if NOT, I would recommend you to use [server-side DataTable](http://datatables.net/examples/server_side/)

Comment: That Works only for the first record.

Comment: So you need to double check on your if statement

Comment: I forget to add Thead, have a look please

Comment: But the Sort icon on the heading and  Paginations are gone

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26564457/5154084 here is the answer, try to check if sorting icons is exist also if requested well

Answer (score 0):

Update this

```
echo '<tr/></tbody></table>';
```

To be

```
echo '</tr>';
```

Then close the tbody, and table tag outside while loop

Comment: Do you mean **echo '</tr>';**