# Datatables Sorting Styles being incorrectly applied to header

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am having an issue after updating from 1.9 to 1.10 in the the header sorting styles seem to be applied to both  and the inside the sort_wrapper div which is inside the  this is causing a dark background to cover the entire head ([image: Bad Header]) as opposed to in 1.9 where it was only applied it inside the sort wrapper ([image: Good Header]) I have tried setting "orderClasses": false in the init object but it seems to make no difference
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. The solution was to override the existing styles, same as the guy here https://stackoverflow.com/a/26564457/1267942