# Is there any way to display sorting icon next to the header text in JQuery Datatable ?

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatables

[image: Like this image]

Is there any way to display the sorting icons of datatable next to the header text like above image ?

Comment: Yes, `datatables` already does it, check out: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html.
If you have any doubts, this question can help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286508/jquery-datatable-doesnt-show-sort-icon

Comment: @RicardoPontual, that's not what OP meant, he meant whether it's possible to display icon *right after* header text.

Comment: Sorting works fine , i just want to place the icon next to the header text like above image , like this <th>Request Name<icon></th> ..

Comment: I understood what you want to do

Answer (score 5):

One possibility is to listen for [draw.dt event](https://datatables.net/reference/event/).

Every time the datatable is drawn you may reposition the ***background-position-x*** (the icon) according to the width of the corresponding column title:

```js
// the following extension comes from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582534/calculating-text-width
$.fn.textWidth = function(){
  var html_org = $(this).html();
  var html_calc = '<span>' + html_org + '</span>';
  $(this).html(html_calc);
  var width = $(this).find('span:first').width();
  $(this).html(html_org);
  return width;
};

$('#example').on( 'draw.dt', function (e) {
  $('#example thead tr th').each(function(idx, ele) {
    var xPos = parseInt((($(ele).width() + $(ele).textWidth()) / 2) + 20);
    $(ele).css('background-position-x',  xPos + 'px')
  })
});

$('#example').DataTable();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2011/04/25</td>
        <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Garrett Winters</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>63</td>
        <td>2011/07/25</td>
        <td>$170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ashton Cox</td>
        <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>66</td>
        <td>2009/01/12</td>
        <td>$86,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
        <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>2012/03/29</td>
        <td>$433,060</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Airi Satou</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>33</td>
        <td>2008/11/28</td>
        <td>$162,700</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2012/12/02</td>
        <td>$372,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>59</td>
        <td>2012/08/06</td>
        <td>$137,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>55</td>
        <td>2010/10/14</td>
        <td>$327,900</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
        <td>Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>39</td>
        <td>2009/09/15</td>
        <td>$205,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sonya Frost</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>2008/12/13</td>
        <td>$103,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jena Gaines</td>
        <td>Office Manager</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>2008/12/19</td>
        <td>$90,560</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
        <td>Support Lead</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>2013/03/03</td>
        <td>$342,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Charde Marshall</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>36</td>
        <td>2008/10/16</td>
        <td>$470,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
        <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>43</td>
        <td>2012/12/18</td>
        <td>$313,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>2010/03/17</td>
        <td>$385,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Michael Silva</td>
        <td>Marketing Designer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>66</td>
        <td>2012/11/27</td>
        <td>$198,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Paul Byrd</td>
        <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>64</td>
        <td>2010/06/09</td>
        <td>$725,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Gloria Little</td>
        <td>Systems Administrator</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>59</td>
        <td>2009/04/10</td>
        <td>$237,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Bradley Greer</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>41</td>
        <td>2012/10/13</td>
        <td>$132,000</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: wow ! this is great .. but only problem i am seeing here is during browser shrink and expand its collapsing .. is there any way to handle this ?

Comment: Excellent. And for left aligned header text use `var xPos = $(ele).textWidth() + 5;`

Answer (score 0):

The way `datatables` use the sort images you can change to any image you want, you just need to set `background-image` in these classes:

```
table.dataTable thead .sorting {
   background-image: /* your image goes here */
}

table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc {
   background-image: /* your image goes here */
}

table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc {
   background-image: /* your image goes here */
}
```

To put it aligned with the column text it's complicated, since the image is put as background of the `th` tag. You need to change the `datatables` code, to generate the text and image as two elements side-by-side, like a `span` and a `div`, for instance. But you can align the image left to the text, adding `background-position: center left;` to the classes above.