# DataTables sort icons not showing

Tags: html, css, laravel, datatables

[image: sort icons do not display on header]

I tried hours to solve this problem, can anyone tell me how can I get those icons or tell me how to make a custom CSS file

files I linked

```
dataTables.bootstrap.min.css
```

and following script files

```
    <script src="js/lib/datatables/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/datatables/cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/datatables/cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/datatables/cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/datatables/cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/datatables/cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/datatables/cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What's the error on the console? Also, what is the HTML on inspect?

Comment: Datatable's website is using CSS and images. Did you check the console like Paras suggested? When we using DT, we use fontawesome with custom CSS.

Comment: Those `<script src="...">` seem messed up, check them out

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26564457/3585500) says that after they copied the datatables CDN files locally they had to fix the icon paths in the CSS file.  Few more answers on that same page too.

Comment: Check if inside the folder of DT exist a folder called images and inside it must be the 5 items for sorting icons if you are using DT with bootstrap and not for ex. jQuery UI. Another suggestion, go to DT web page and download the official package you can build selecting components and tools you need to use and save all the folder locally.