# DataTables Missing Sort Icons After Switching From CDN to Local Hosted Files

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, datatables, icons

I am using DataTables to format tables on an MVC application. I am using the client side JQuery implementation. I was using the CDN without issue other than loading time. I used their [download builder](https://datatables.net/download/index) very successfully and pulled out the minified CSS and JQuery files from the whole folder of downloads so I could bundle them with the rest of my files. The DataTables works except for the sorting icons.
I am getting a "Not found" error on only those icons.
Why would the icons have worked with the CDN, but not when hosted locally?

Answer (score 0):

I saw [several Stack Overflow posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286508/jquery-datatable-doesnt-show-sort-icon) and even a [DataTables forum](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/47823/column-sort-icons) while researching this, but the posts don't seem to apply to their download builder. Several of them suggest adjusting the local file references, but not where to get the icons. I saw in the minified CSS file where the icons were referenced like

```
table.dataTable thead .sorting{background-image:url("DataTables-1.10.16/images/sort_both.png")}
```

I realized it had to be an issue of the icon reference so I looked for where to download the icons to place in my images folder. **Then I realized the download builder had placed the icons in the DataTables-1.10.16 folder.** I moved them to my ~/Content/images folder and updated the CSS references (there are 4) to:

```
table.dataTable thead .sorting{background-image:url("images/sort_both.png")}
```

It worked perfectly after that.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the datatable was looking for the images in **~content/images**, but in my solution explorer I could see they were in **~content/datatables/images**.

I copied the whole **~/Content/DataTables/Images** folder to **~/Content/Images** and that fixed it.

It may be possible to just move the **~/Content/DataTables/Images** folder but I wanted to leave a copy of it there in case moving it broke any other references.