# Why are my Bootstrap data table column heading sort icons not displaying?

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, datatables

I have a Bootstrap 4 data table, and sorting the rows by clicking the column headings is working fine, but the little up and down facing triangle icons are not appearing. I've tried both `thead-dark` and `thead-light` classes so I don't think the problem is the color.

Here is a sample of the HTML with which I create the table (this is using the Rails ERB  templating system that substitutes my text for the `table_id` and `col_sort_tooltip` variables).

```
    <div class="table-responsive data-table-div" >
      <table id="<%= table_id %>" class="data-table table thead-dark table-striped">
        <thead class="thead-dark" title="<%= col_sort_tooltip %>" alt="<%= col_sort_tooltip %>" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Title</th>
          <th scope="col">Performer</th>
          <th scope="col">Rights Admin</th>
          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Listen</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
```

Where do you suggest I look to fix this?

Comment: Any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: No, no errors in the console.

Comment: Do you import datatables css?

Comment: Thanks for that clue. The article at https://aarvy.me/blog/2019/09/21/datatables-with-bootstrap-4-minimal-setup-in-rails-6/ did not say anything about this, but the article at https://www.vic-l.com/how-to-add-datatables-to-webpacker-in-rails/ said to add this:    `require("datatables.net-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css")` to `application.js`. Now I see the up and down facing arrow in the column heading, but oddly, they are flush against the top of the heading.

Comment: You can see the effect I mean in the table column headings at https://tepper-bennett.com/songs.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286508/jquery-datatable-doesnt-show-sort-icon
**please go through this reference too**